# PyTorch Image Upscaler

Tags: pytorch

i have downloaded pretrained weights for an ESRGAN upscaling model. The weights i downloaded come from here: https://huggingface.co/gemasai/4x_NMKD-Siax_200k/tree/main i can use this inside comfy ui and it works like a charm. I want to implement this inside an app i am developing but i can not get it to work. The main problem i guess is to have a model that matches the weights. Thats how the keys in the pretrained weights look like:

```
Keys in pretrained state dict:
odict_keys(['model.0.weight', 'model.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv1.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv1.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv2.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv2.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv3.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv3.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv4.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv4.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv5.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB1.conv5.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv1.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv1.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv2.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv2.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv3.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv3.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv4.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv4.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv5.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB2.conv5.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv1.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv1.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv2.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv2.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv3.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv3.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv4.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv4.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv5.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.0.RDB3.conv5.0.bias'
....
'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv1.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv1.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv2.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv2.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv3.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv3.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv4.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv4.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv5.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB1.conv5.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv1.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv1.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv2.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv2.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv3.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv3.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv4.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv4.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv5.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB2.conv5.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv1.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv1.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv2.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv2.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv3.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv3.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv4.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv4.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv5.0.weight', 'model.1.sub.22.RDB3.conv5.0.bias',
'model.1.sub.23.weight', 'model.1.sub.23.bias', 'model.3.weight',
'model.3.bias', 'model.6.weight', 'model.6.bias', 'model.8.weight',
'model.8.bias', 'model.10.weight', 'model.10.bias'])
```

Are there any ESRGAN models that would work for the weights?